# Painting a trail over a Path in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I have a image moving around a complex path made up with multiple line segments. I want to draw over the path as if the image is leaving a 'snail trail' over the path, is there anyway I can do this ? I have looked at multiple examples of similar things but nothing is suitable yet. Thanks
Image included as example :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Path Animations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970561.aspx) with `MatrixTransform` to achieve this motion. Depending on the content of your "Complex Path" you might then have multiple other `StoryBoard`'s along the same animating path with different alpha values to thus give a trail effect.

Also have a look over at this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582273/wpf-animation-of-ekg-signal-animate-object-along-path) for the above concept applied to a `Path`

Comment: Yea sorry should have said am already using path animations to move the image over the path, I just need to leave a trail behind it, looked at SO question link and its all in XAML, I need C#.

Comment: Well converting the StoryBoard to c# shouldn't be an issue for you  right? Concept is what is important for the trail. You basically have clone elements of the Main path each with different opacity. Each of these clone elements use a storyboard for their animation with the BeginTime on a slight delay to each other. You thus have your path cloned say 3 times(opacity 1, .7, .3) and then you create the storyboard in code behind and set the BeginTime accordingly(0, 0.05, 0.1). Now when you execute the Storyboards, the elements animating give the trail effect.

Comment: Im having trouble understanding the XAML to be honest, im really not sure how this works ? When u say copies of my path what actual copies of the path class and its associated geometry ? Also the example is not leaving a permanent trail on the path.

Comment: Can you post your path animation code you have. We can then maybe tweak it for a trail and explain on it